# Comparing UTF8 encoded chars

Tags: c++, unix, utf-8

There is a csv  file which has the many different languages encoded in utf-8. I have to parse the file and validate for invalid characters. 
I have written a sample program below as shown…

```
int main(void)
{
    string invalidUTF8Chars = ""; // Invalid UTF-8 Chars array.
    invalidUTF8Chars+= "\u00A0";
    invalidUTF8Chars+= "\u005E";
    invalidUTF8Chars+= "\u00FE";
    invalidUTF8Chars+= "\u00BA";
    invalidUTF8Chars+= "\u00AF";

    FILE* fp;
    char ch;
    fp = fopen("unicodeUTF8TextFile.txt","r");

    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        while(( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ) // Reading byte by byte form input file.
        {
            //if (strchr(invalidUTF8Chars.c_str(), ch)) // How do I validate here?
            {
                printf("Invalid character\n");
            }
        }
    }
        return 0;
}
```

How do I compare the data read from the file against the invalid chars?

Comment: `char ch;` is a massive mistake; please study the <cstdio> API carefully before proceeding.

Comment: `string invalidUTF8Chars = "";` is not an array. it's just a string containing all your invalid "chars".

Comment: Your literals should be of the form `u8"\u00A0"` etc. if you actually want UTF-8. Your current code doesn't use UTF-8, but rather the system's narrow encoding (which may or may not be the same).

Comment: @KerrekSB is saying it should be `int`, to give space for EOF.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: How do I compare utf8 chars?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Point taken, and made changes in my local.

Answer (score 0):

When `strchr()` fails to find a character it returns a NULL-pointer. What you need to do is to check if the return was a NULL-pointer or not:

```
if(strchr(invalidUTF8Chars.c_str(), ch) == nullptr){
    printf("Invalid character\n");
}
```

Here's the [strchr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) reference for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid character for UTF-8 may either mean that the UTF-8 encoding is invalid and doesn't correspond to any character, or that the UTF-8 decoding will lead to a character that you don't want.

You are interested in the second variant, where each character is encoded as one or more bytes in UTF-8, specifically "\u005E" is one byte in UTF-8 and the others are 2 bytes.

Thus you cannot reject individual bytes in your example, but would either need to decode to Unicode-characters or read everything as UTF-8 and then find the issues using something like:

```
  if (strstr(readFile, u8"\u00A0") != nullptr || strstr(readFile, u8"\u005E") != nullptr ... ) printf("Found bad character\n");
```